# Android - How to use onKeyDown?

Tags: android, input

I would like to use the onKeyDown event to react to hardware buttons on my phone. So I added the following to my class:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
...
```

But this gives me the following compiler error:

> "The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) of type MyClass must override or
>   implement a supertype method"

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your `MyClass` extend a `Activity`?  It must do so in order for you to get the key events.

More info at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown